# Updating an Uploaded Zip File without re-uploading the whole files

Tags: zip, upload

Imagine I have uploaded a zip file which contains thousands of images and its size is about 2GB. Now I want to add 100 new pictures which their size is about 10MB. The only way I can imagine is that I add these images to my 2GB collection, then upload the whole collection AGAIN!!! But I'm looking for a way that I can inject only new files without re-uploading the whole collection. So is there any way to do this? any good way or software?

Comment: Is it torrent file?

Comment: No, just a simple .zip file, for example mysite.com/file.zip

Comment: I don't if it worked or not but I found this [FTP Software](http://www.coffeecup.com/free-ftp/) and its this feature `Easy File Management: Free FTP offers full-fledged local and remote file management, so you can add, move, and launch files all from inside the program. Everything works like you would expect: Double-click an executable file to launch it. Drag and drop files in and out of the local file browser, and they’ll be moved accordingly.` may be do the magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have command line access to the server?  If you have or can install a zip utility on the server, you can unpack the zip on the server, upload the files to the directory, and then re-zip it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I should check if I have command line access, but if yes can you introduce me a zip utility?

Comment: It depends on your server OS and how much access, if any, you have to that server. For instance, I have root access to a (remotely hosted) Linux server, so I have the ability to install things if they are not there by default. But in my experience, most Linux servers come with a [zip command](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_zip.htm). A Windows server can be bit different, but the ones I have used had some sort of utility available if you have command line access. Or even better, if you have remote desktop access, just install a zip utility like on a PC.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer would depend on how you are uploading the zip, and how you can manipulate it once its uploaded.

Unless you can add it directly to the zip, where you uploaded it, you would need to re-compress the images, then re-upload.

Comment: I'm uploading a zip file on target server by cute ftp software. so what should I do to avoid re-uploading and wasting time and traffic?